# Tengo tres DefaultListModel y deseo unirlas para usarlas en un sola lista. El orden del nuevo DefaultListModel quiero que sea de alta a baja

Tags: lista, java-swing

DefaultListModel modelBaja,modelModerada,modelAlta;
DefaultListModel modelPrioridad;

String dato = this.txtDato.getText();

```
    this.modelMemoria.addElement(dato);
    this.miCola.enqueue(dato);
    
    recorrerCola();
    
    this.txtDato.setText("");
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            txtDato.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    
    String prioridad = (String) Prioridades.getSelectedItem();
    
    if(prioridad.equals("Baja")){this.modelBaja.addElement(dato);}
    else if (prioridad.equals("Moderada")) {this.modelModerada.addElement(dato);}
    else if (prioridad.equals("Alta")) {this.modelAlta.addElement(dato);}
    
    
    this.modelPrioridad...
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

1 lista -> 1 modelo, eso no se puede cambiar.

Lo que tienes que hacer es que tu modelo trabaje con tus requerimientos.

Por ejemplo, puedes mantener las tres listas por separado, y para cualquier cambio al hacer la inserción lo que haces es eliminar todos los elementos del modelo e ir añadiendo, por orden, los elementos de las tres listas.

Esta misma lógica la puedes encapsular dentro de una subclase de DefaultListModel a la que le añadas los métodos correspondientes, lo cual es una solución mucho más en línea con lo que es Java.

Ya más avanzado sería crear tu propia implementación de ListModel, de forma que no vaya creando y eliminando elementos de una lista cada vez. Por ejemplo, podrías mantener una única lista de un objeto que contenga el valor y la prioridad (*). Insertar un elemento de una prioridad sería meterlo en esa única lista, en la posición correspondiente.

(*) Para Java 14 y superiores infórmate sobre los record (**).

(**) Y, ya puestos, existe una clase java.util.PriorityQueue desde Java 5.